# Why my Producer Consumer program ends?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

As an exercise, I wrote the following code to practice the Producer/ Consumer pattern:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Entity> entities;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            Entity en = new Entity();
            System.out.println("Producing entity: " + Integer.toString(i));
            en.setName(Integer.toString(i));
            entities.add(en);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<Entity> entities;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Consuming entity: "
                  + entities.take().getName());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class MainPCClass {
    BlockingQueue<Entity> entities = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Entity>(5);

    public void start(){
        //start the producer
        new Thread(new Producer(entities)).start();
        //start the consumer
        new Thread(new Consumer(entities)).start();
    }
}
```

I expect that given the while(true) above in the consumer, My program never ends and the consumer thread gets blocked as the queue is empty after the producer produced everything. Why is that? Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong? My program runs and end very smoothly.

Comment: Your expectation is reasonable - how do you run your program? Is anything printed out?

Comment: Where is your method that starts the threads?

Comment: from looking at it, the producer should add 20 jobs, then finish. The consumer will block after the 20th jobs, waiting for the next. What is the output you get?

Comment: The only thing I can see may confuse things is the use of `add`. Because you have a bounded queue, the queue will throw a RuntimeException when `add` is called when the queue is full. However, only your producer thread should die and the consumer threads should continue running.

Comment: For some reason, after restarting my IDE, everything works as expected! Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

- Your program never stops, because the Threads you use are not set to be daemon threads. The JVM will finish only if all remaining threads are daemon threads.
- When running your program you will potentially get a `IllegalStateException: Queue full`, because the producer exceeds the limit of 5 you set the list to.